# Why is the timestamp suffix missing from the artifact filename in my local repo? (Maven 3.3.3)

Tags: maven, pom.xml, dependency-management, nexus, snapshot

When I deploy a snapshot version of my project to Nexus the filename is stored in the snapshots repository with a timestamp suffix as follows:

```
my-lib-0.0.1-20151209.150900-1.jar
```

This is what I expect.

At the same time my local repository is updated with the new version of the snapshot but without the timestamp suffix. What is stored there is:

```
my-lib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I'm new to Maven and Nexus and have been playing around with them for a couple of days. Previously, the local repo was being updated with the *same* filename as what was in the Nexus snapshots repository.

Which property controls this behaviour?

These are the settings in my pom:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://nexus.bxd.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>

    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <url>http://nexus.bxd.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

These are my `server` settings in `settings.xml`:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <username>deployment</username>
        <password>***</password>
    </server>

    <server>
        <id>releases</id>
        <username>deployment</username>
        <password>***</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

**UPDATE**

I've noticed that if I delete my local repo and deploy my library then the local repo is updated with `my-lib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

If I delete my local repo and build another library that depends on `my-lib` then the local repo is updated with `my-lib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and the latest timestamped version too.

Comment: Which version of Maven is this (more precisely)? Are you extending a parent? in the `<snapshotRepository>` add `<uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>`.

Comment: Maven version 3.3.3. I'm not extending a parent. My understanding is that `uniqueVersion` is ignored in version 3.

Comment: By default it's value is set to true, unless you're inheriting from some parent and that overrides it somehow. Have a look here: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/maven-model/maven.html.

Comment: See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-Non-uniqueSnapshotDeployments

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Either way, are you extending from a parent, or not?

Comment: Also, is this an assembly built using the `maven-assembly-plugin`, or something? I just had a look at my local repository (I'm also building with `3.3.3`) and the only `SNAPSHOT` projects that didn't have a timestamped version in my local repository, were such that we produced by the `maven-assembly-plugin`). Without seeing your full `pom.xml`, it's really hard to tell, mate...

Comment: I'm not extending a parent. And yes, I am building this as an assembly but I don't think that has anything to do with the behaviour I'm seeing. In fact, I'm now fairly confident that the behaviour is actually correct. Just wanted a concrete explanation that I could refer to.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, if you're using the `maven-assembly-plugin`, or are altering the `finalName` of the artifact.

Comment: Can you point me to the source where this is specified? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a specific page documenting this that I could point you to, but I am speaking from my long-term exposure to Maven.